# Sencha Touch 2 - Getting messageProperty after save() on a model

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs4, sencha-touch-2

I've got a User model that gets POSTed to the server to create a user on the system. The response is basically:

```
{
    success: false,
    message: "User already exists"
}
```

Cool, within my model I have a REST Proxy. The proxy has a JSONReader attached to it as well with the following:

```
messageProperty: 'message',
successProperty: 'success'
```

so I create my user and save it with something like:

```
var user = Ext.create('App.model.User', {name: "Bill"});
user.save(function (records, operation) {
    console.log(records); 
    console.log(operation);
});
```

But I can't see anywhere to grab the error message that was returned from the server. All I can grab is: isSuccessful() which seems to correctly say false.
There doesn't seem to be ANYTHING in the documentation about this. I can't understand why something like this isn't included or how I'm missing it.

operation.getResponse(); returns null as well. I've also tried passing in a config with success, failure and callback... seems to be nothing there for me

Thanks, Dom

Answer (score 1):

Try operation.getResultSet().getMessage(). I haven't tried it, but looking at the source code, it seems like this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can pass in a object with a success and fail methods.  From the docs http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-save

*options : Object/Function
Options to pass to the proxy. Config object for Ext.data.Operation. If you pass a function, this will automatically become the callback method. For convenience the config object may also contain success and failure methods in addition to callback - they will all be invoked with the Model and Operation as arguments.*

So you should be able to do:

```
var user = Ext.create('App.model.User', {name: "Bill"});
user.save({
    success: function(){

    },
    failure: function(){

    }
});
```

I don't know what is the callbacks, but usually what I do to find out:

```
success:function(a,b,c,d){
    console.log(a,b,c,d);
}
```

and then look at the data in my console and rename the vars accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = Ext.create('App.model.User', {name: "Bill"});
user.save({
            success : function(){
                console.log('success', arguments);
            },
            failure : function(model, operation){
                var reader = model.getProxy().getReader(),
                    message = reader.getMessage(reader.rawData)
                console.log('failure message : ' + message);

            }
        });
```